# How to expand a register value in a \write argument (plain TeX)?

Tags: plain-tex, write

I am using `\write` to output table of contents information. While the correct heading counter information apears in the headings itself, the TOC headings have the number of the last heading of a page. So the `\write` command seems to be delayd until a page eject. How can I flush a `\write` at the time a heading macro is processed?

My current section macro begins with:

```
\edef\SecWr#1{\write0{\line{\hskip2em\hbox to2em{\the\ChaptNo.\the\SecNo\hfil}
    #1\leaderfill\noexpand\folio}}}
\def\Sec#1{\advance\SecNo by1
    \SecWr{#1}
```

The page number is displayed correctly but e.g. `\the\ChaptNo` is displayed as `0`?

Comment: It looks like you have to expand the heading number before it is passed to `\write`. By adding `\immediate` before `\write`, the write is not delayed, but you need the delayed writing for the page number, which is known at page shipout time and usually not before.

Comment: How can I do this expansion? Lets assume I want to use `\write{\the\ChapNo}` (this is not a useful example but a minimum one).

Comment: `\expandafter` can help: `\expandafter\write\expandafter\handle\expandafter{\the\ChapNo}`. Or the whole `\write` expression can be put inside an `\edef` with protecting the page number from expansion, e.g. `\noexpand\folio`.

Comment: My example had been too simple. The actual is now `\expandafter\write0\expandafter\handle\expandafter{\line{\hskip2em\hbox to2em{\the\ChapNo.\the\SecNo\hfil}#1\leaderfill\the\pageno}}` which doesn't compile.

Comment: Using `\edef\Test#1{\write0{\line{\hskip2em\hbox to2em{\the\ChapNo.\the\SecNo\hfil}#1\leaderfill\the\noexpand\pageno}}}` and then `\Test{#1}` inside my `\section` macros does also not work.

Comment: `\expandafter` can only jump over *one* token and you have to go the full length to `\the\ChapNo`. Therefore the `\edef` is probably the easier road. Here, you also need to protect `\the` from expansion: `\noexpand\the\noexpand\pageno`. However, in plain TeX the command for printing the page number is `\folio` and one `\noexpand` suffices: `\noexpand\folio`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The chapter and section number need to be expanded at the time, the `\write` is issued, but the expansion of the page number `\folio` needs to be delayed to the page shipout time, when the page number is definitely known.

Example:

```
\def\tocentry#1#2{%
  \line{%
    \hskip2em\relax
    \hbox to 2em{#1\hfil}%
    #2\leaderfill
    \folio
  }%
}
\def\SecWr#1{%
  \begingroup
    \let\folio\relax % prevent expansion of `\folio` during `\edef`
    \edef\next{%
      \write0{\noexpand\tocentry{\the\ChaptNo.\the\SecNo}{#1}}%
    }%
    \next
  \endgroup
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Whether a macro is defined with `\def` or `\edef` is only important at *definition time*, not at usage time.

Thus, you don't want to `\edef\SecWr`, which would fix forever the value of `\ChaptNo` and `\SecNo` to the value at definition time (which is zero).

If you want a macro that expands its argument at usage time you can exploit `expl3`, that also works with Plain TeX, provided you run an e-TeX engine like `pdftex` (not with Knuth TeX).

```
\input expl3-generic
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \test_sec_wr:nn
 {
  \tocsection{#1}{#2}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \test_sec_wr:nn { x }
\cs_set_eq:NN \SecWr \test_sec_wr:xn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\tocsection#1#2{%
  \write0{%
    \line{\hskip2em\hbox to2em{#1\hfil}#2\leaderfill\folio}%
  }%
}

\def\Sec#1{\advance\SecNo by1 \SecWr{\the\ChaptNo.\the\SecNo}{#1}}
```

Here's a full example (with `\leaderfill` defined as `\relax` just for testing, as I don't know what's your definition).

```
\input expl3-generic
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \test_sec_wr:nn
 {
  \tocsection{#1}{#2}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \test_sec_wr:nn { x }
\cs_set_eq:NN \SecWr \test_sec_wr:xn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\tocsection#1#2{%
  \write0{%
    \line{\hskip2em\hbox to2em{#1\hfil}#2\leaderfill\folio}%
  }%
}

\def\Sec#1{\advance\SecNo by1 \SecWr{\the\ChaptNo.\the\SecNo}{#1}}

\newcount\ChaptNo
\newcount\SecNo
\let\leaderfill\relax % just for testing

\ChaptNo=3 % just for testing

\Sec{Section Title}
\Sec{Section Title}
\Sec{Section Title}

\bye
```

The macro `\test_sec_wr:nn` is defined as a normal macro, but then we define a variant that fully e`x`pands its first argument and use it as `\SecWr`. Here's the output on the terminal:

```
\hbox to\hsize {\hskip 2em\hbox to2em{3.1\hfil }Section Title\leaderfill 1}
\hbox to\hsize {\hskip 2em\hbox to2em{3.2\hfil }Section Title\leaderfill 1}
\hbox to\hsize {\hskip 2em\hbox to2em{3.3\hfil }Section Title\leaderfill 1}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution! I nethertheless did use Heiko's solution since that it works with "old" `tex` too is a more general approach. Finally I may indeed use `pdftex` but there the general solution may also work. I come back to your example when I run into problems with the other solution.